# Sending Multiple Payloads Over Socket in Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, iis

### Edit: the problem is with IIS, not with the Perl code I'm using. Someone else was talking about the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/491445/1179075

Long-time reader here, first time posting.

So I'm working on some existing code in Perl that does the following:

> 1. Create socket
> 2. Send some data
> 3. Close socket
> 4. Loop back to 1 until all data is sent

To avoid the overhead of creating and closing sockets all the time, I decided to do this:

> 1. Create socket
> 2. Send some data
> 3. Loop back to 2 until all data is sent
> 4. Close socket

The thing is, only the first payload is being sent - all subsequent ones are ignored. I'm sending this data to a .NET web service, and IIS isn't receiving the data at all. Somehow the socket is being closed, and I have no further clue why.

Here's the script I'm using to test my new changes:

```
use IO::Socket;
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr => $hostname, PeerPort => 80, Proto => "tcp", Timeout => "1000") || die "Failure: $! ";
while(1){
    my $sent = $sock->send($basic_http_ping_message);
    print "$sent\n";
    sleep(1);
}
close($sock);
```

So this doesn't work - IIS only receives the very first ping. If I move `$sock`'s assignment and closing into the loop, however, IIS correctly receives every single ping.

Am I just using sockets incorrectly here, or is there some arcane setting in IIS that I need to change?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you need to do this at the socket level? If not, you should look into modules such as LWP::UserAgent or WWW::Mechanize (search CPAN).

Comment: Not really - it's mostly because the existing code uses sockets. I've taken a look at both modules, and both seem to be overkill for what I'm doing, especially Mechanize. All I need this code to do is to send data somewhat frequently to a web service.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is buffering. Turn off buffering on the socket, or flush it after each write (closing the socket has the side-effect of flushing it).

Comment: Did you try _$sock->flush()_ after the send()? $| = 1 applies to the current filehandle, and you would have to _select_ $sock first for it to be effective.

Comment: Tried it, still nothing. Could the Reuse/ReuseAddr parameter be prematurely closing the socket?

Answer (score 0):

What output are you getting?  You have a print after the `send()`, if `send()` fails, it will return `undef`.  You can print out the error like:

```
     my $sent = $sock->send($msg);
     die "Failed send: $!\n" unless defined $sent;
     print "Sent $sent bytes\n";
```

My own guess is that the service that you're connecting to is closing the connection, which is why only one gets through, and also why creating a new connection each time would work.

Comment: I'm getting 395, the number of bytes in my message. This is true for every send(). I've also tried to diagnose the problems I'm having with the web service, but not only is my web service not receiving the messages, neither is IIS (or at maybe IIS is receiving them, but not logging them).